# Cover cuts in cut planes

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When I use the function `viewer.setCutPlanes()` the planes that are cut are not covered:

[image]
[image]

But using the viewer's section analysis tool plane cut, they do get covered (and each cover is part of its own node which is nice):

[image]

How can I add those covers to the model when using `viewer.setCutPlanes()`?

PS: I found the section tool extension in the viewer, but it seems all of its relevant functions are private. Should I try to copy this extension and expose the necessary functions there? Is there a repo with the ES6 version of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no ES6 module for the `Forge Viewer`. The `Viewer3D.setCutPlanes()` is an utility method for producing `ThreeJS` clipping planes only, and the cut-cover feature is archived by the `Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Section.SectionTool` now.

Functions listed below must be copied from the `SectionTool` extension if you wanna perform this feature under self control:

1. `getDiffuseColor()`
2. `init_three_triangulator()`
3. `init_three_intersector()`
4. `updateCapMeshes()`

Besides, the `_viewer` variable in those private functions above should be replaced by the `Viewer3DImpl` instance, i.e. the `Viewer3D.impl`. Or you can change function declaration of `updateCapMeshes` just like below:

```
function updateCapMeshes( _viewer, plane ) {

  init_three_triangulator();
  init_three_intersector();

  // ... Original content of updateCapMeshes below ...
}
```

Call modified `updateCapMeshes` function to create cut-cover like this way:

```
//-- Helper function to create your own cut planes.
function createMyOwnPlane( _viewer, _sectionPlanes ) {
  if (_sectionPlanes.length === 1) {
     updateCapMeshes(_viewer, new THREE.Plane().setComponents(_sectionPlanes[0].x, _sectionPlanes[0].y, _sectionPlanes[0].z, _sectionPlanes[0].w));
  }
  _viewer.setCutPlanes(_sectionPlanes);
}


//-- Call functions here.
var viewer = viewerApp.getCurrentViewer();
createMyOwnPlane( viewer.impl, [ new THREE.Vector4(0, 0, 1, 0) ] );
```

And you will get results like this picture without the `TransformControl`:
[Result of createMyOwnPlane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTPAA.jpg)

BTW, cut-cover can be removed by this way~

```
var oldsection = viewer.impl.sceneAfter.getObjectByName("section");
if (oldsection)
  viewer.impl.sceneAfter.remove(oldsection);

viewer.setCutPlanes();
```

Comment: @eason-kang Do you know if this is planned to be a public Viewer3D API in the future? It's a bit fragile to copy the private implementation. Thanks.